# CSS: Margin on image leaves an empty space

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin

So I have this HTML:

```
<div id="red_box">

<img id="myImage" alt="Fechar caixa de texto" src="http://quindigo.eti.br/Imagens/IconePequenoQuindigo.png">

<span id="spanOfTheBox">the Text </span>

</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#red_box{
    width:40%;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    border:5px double red;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:50px;
}

#myImage{
    margin-left:102%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#spanOfTheBox{
    display : inline-block;
    width : 100%;                  
    height : inherit;
}
```

As you can see in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1anc7rgy/3/), the `span` element remains below the `img` element. It seems that the margin-left applied to the img occupies the space that could be filled whit the span. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Do you want some solution?

Comment: Please, it would be delightful

Comment: One solution: https://jsfiddle.net/1anc7rgy/4/

Comment: What a strange way to do this thing... What are you trying to achieve? You want the img to always hover right ouside the box at the top? Use `position: absolute`.

Comment: @Rudie great! It worked! Just ask myself why position:relative didn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the span to occupy that space consider using floats to get both elements side by side.

If you wanted to keep this margin-left you could modify the position attribute of the  to absolute/fixed and place it in that space as well, but the float solution would be far cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the margin occupies space. Remove it/lessen it and it should work out.

Comment: Ok, but I need that image exactly there. How can I achieve it?

Comment: As the other guy mentioned you can use floats to position, and then use a small amount of margin, say 10% to position further